# Rails Active Storage prevents upload when mime type is empty

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm uploading a file using Direct Upload and Active Storage in Rails 6. When uploading a `.stl` file I am met with the following error `Mime::Type::InvalidMimeType ("" is not a valid MIME type)` which results in a 406 error.

When checking the file with JS it does also not return a Mime type. The file type is simply empty.

This is the case for all `.stl` files I've tried. Image files work as expected.

I've added the correct Mimetype to a rails initializer using `Mime::Type.register "model/stl", :stl`. But of course this makes no difference.

The file is submitted in JS using DirectUpload.

```js
  new DirectUpload(file, url, this)
```

There is no file validation.

So essentially my questions are;

- Why is the mimetype empty?
- Is there a different way of verifying the filetype?
- Can I somehow set the mimetype without causing security issues?
- Can I somehow accept the file anyway, even if the mimetype is empty?

Comment: From active storage's code, it uses `file.type` to get the content type (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/assets/javascripts/activestorage.js#L553), what does `file.type` return if you debug the variable using dev tools?

Comment: @arieljuod It's empty, simply "".

Comment: From the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/type it looks like your browser (or your system, I'm not sure) doesn't know what's the file mime type from the extension (that would be the reason it is blank). I guess you can override the controller action that's called by direct upload and set the mime type that you want. Check the error log to get the controller and the action. Given that the mime type returned by file.type only depends on the extension I wouldn't worry about hardcoding that mime type if the extension of the received file is `.slt`.

Comment: @arieljuod Interesting, thank you. I came across this list of Media types: https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#model. STL is mentioned in there, so I would assume it should work. I've tried it in Chrome and Firefox, both result in the same error.

In any case, do you have any advise on how I could overwrite this action? Currently my controller is very basic Rails, but the file never even reaches that point so I'm uncertain what to change. The console mentions `ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController#create`. Is this something I can overwrite somehow?

Comment: You could create your own controller that extends ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController, override the create action (copy the original https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/direct_uploads_controller.rb and set the mime_type as the content_type params) and then change te route to your action instead of the original (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/config/routes.rb)

Comment: @arieljuod Awesome your advise got me there, it's working! I'd like to award you this bounty but I don't seem to be able to award it to a direct comment.

Comment: Ok, I'll add an asnwer with everything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the problem seems to be that ActiveStorage uses javascripts File.type method to determine the mime type, which is not too reliable https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/type (it only checks the extension and it looks like it depends on the operating system's settings).

Since you already know what mime type you want the file to be and given that it already uses a not too reliable method, I guess it's ok to set the file type manually if the file extension is the one you are expeting to be.

In order to override the original direct upload action, you can create a new controller to extend the original https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/direct_uploads_controller.rb. On your custom controller override the `create` action and set the value of `params[:blob][:content_type]` if it's empty and then just do the same or call super.

For DirectUpload to use your controller and action, you need to change the route that direct upload uses https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/config/routes.rb. Just add a new route for your controller using the same url `/direct_upload`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the closing paragraph of arieljuod's answer:

The source route is prefixed; your overriding route must include the full path. For instance, to override the default create action:

```
post "/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads" => "your_controller_name#create"
```